# Comma placement for "to identify requirements for and develop a Python script"

Tags: grammar, commas

Are commas required/appropriate for the sentence snippet in the title?

For instance:

> to identify requirements for, and develop, a Python script

Also, what is the grammatical term for a sentence structured this way?

Comment: You're hearing some kind of boundary intonation, but it's not comma intonation. In print, I'd use parentheses or dashes.

Comment: Can you elaborate with an example?

Comment: _identify requirements for -- and develop -- a Python script_, or _identify requirements for (and develop) a Python script_

Comment: I see, do you know where I could learn more about the differences between these various boundary intonations and when to use them?

Comment: Is this what you're referring to?https://www.quickanddirtytips.com/articles/dashes-parentheses-and-commas/#:~:text=In%20general%2C%20you%20can%20think,pirate%20dashing%20into%20a%20fray.

Comment: I'm thinking this: Python Scripts - Identify Requirements and Develop Them.

Comment: Personally I'd repeat the word 'to' giving "to identify the rqequirements for and to develop a Python script". In my opinion that reduces ambiguity and helps to make the boundaries of the phrases clearer.